# Is there a way to control an android device with a javascript program on a desktop computer?

Tags: node.js, ide

I am trying trying to make a program that includes controlling user actions on android (e.g. swiping, tapping), by running a program on a desktop computer. Is there any way, say an IDE that allows me to do so?

An IDE named [Auto.js](https://github.com/clearw5/Auto.js/blob/main/README-en.md) really suited my needs. It includes an app that is downloaded on the android device and a Node.js package for desktop, so that the code on the desktop can be sent into the android device. It contains functions to control tapping and swiping on the mobile device, which is what I need.

Unfortunately, this IDE has been removed, and I can't quite find a similar one that suites my language and needs.

Comment: *"Unfortunately, this IDE has been removed ..."*  - I wonder why.  User security perhaps?

Comment: It is said that they have put the tool behind a paywall, but now accessing any of their sites result in a HTTP 514 error.

Comment: Maybe you need this: http://selendroid.io/